# Jquery Breaks an OnClick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been satisfactorily using a submit button like this

```
<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="document.booking.submit()" class="buttonavail"></a>
```

for some time. The class defines the position of the button and it's appearance.

Now I have added a Jquery script to the page, and the button no longer works. The script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabcontent > div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
    $("#tabs li:first").attr("id","current"); // Activate first tab
    $("#tabcontent div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

    $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#tabcontent > div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
    });
$('#prices').load('../prices.php?hid=<?php echo $hid;?>');
});
```

Presumably it is something to do with having "javascript:void()" in the href, but I can't see why. Is there an alternative way of writing the href to get both things working together?

PARTIAL SOLUTION
The problem was not really what I thought it was. In the end I found that the parent page and the page being loaded by Jquery both contained a  with the same name. Re-naming one of the forms solved that part of the problem.

However now that that is out of the way I am finding another issue that appears to be a conflict between two bits of Jquery. I've asked another question about that at [Jquery - Scripts are conflicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21584904/jquery-scripts-are-conflicting)

Comment: there isn't any text in the ancor tag

Comment: Where are you placing this javascript code?

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the void statement to see what happens?

Comment: There's no text in the anchor tag because the class incorporates a button, via a sprite.
The javascript code is in the <head> of the page. The "a href" is in the <body>.
Taking out just "void()" makes no difference. Taking everything out of the href just makes the page reload on click.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function as below. Add the submit in last line of the function like I shown

```
 $('#tabs a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest("li").attr("id") == "current"){ //detection for current tab
         return       
        }
        else{             
        $("#tabcontent > div").hide(); //Hide all content
        $("#tabs li").attr("id",""); //Reset id's
        $(this).parent().attr("id","current"); // Activate this
        $('#' + $(this).attr('name')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
        }
        $(this).submit() **// ADD HERE**
    });
```

Comment: Yeah this might actually be better than my answer - I didn't realise OP wanted both to work together. +1

Answer (score 0):

`$('#tabs a').click` is your problem. You are overwriting the click event for the `<a>` tag with this code.

You can update the jQuery code to this:

`$('#tabs a:not(.buttonavail)').click`

Comment: It's not the "$('#tabs a').click" that is causing it. My problematical "a href" is not inside the "tabs" div. However you have set me thinking down a different route and I have tried deleting bits of the script line-by-line. Done that way I have isolated the problem to the "$('#prices).load" line, though I have absolutely no idea why.
Any further thoughts would be much appreciated. Meanwhile I shall continue fiddling away to try to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: The anchored button isn't in the div you're reloading by any chance is it? If you're replacing the `<a>` tag - even with an identical tag, it will lose reference and potentially break the click event

Comment: No, they're in totally different parts of the page.
HOWEVER, I have found that by putting a different file name in place of prices.php, everything works OK. So I am concluding that there is something in prices.php that is causing the problem. I'm now working through that, trying to find the conflict.

Comment: If the "prices.php" file has a DOM element called `booking` you might have trouble with: `onclick="document.booking.submit()"` because there would now be two "booking" elements on the page

Comment: Full marks to Askanison4! You hit the nail exactly on the head. I've just been flogging through prices.php deleting bits of code until I finally homed it in to a form with the name booking. I haven't revised the file and tested it yet, but it's looking pretty clear that that's where the problem was.

Comment: Glad you found it! :)